# Azure: which of my cloud services has a specific IP address?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

We have a rogue Azure cloud service which is hammering one of our services.

We know its IP address, but how can we find out the name of the cloud service (i.e the resource group), given its IP address?

Comment: Maybe post this to ServerFault? But... if nslookup doesn't help, you could easily go through your list of cloud services (unless you have hundreds of them...).  You might have luck with `Get-AzureService` cmdlet as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have RM deployments in azure since you asked for resource group.

If what you have is a public IP address

```
Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress | Where-Object {$_.IpAddress -eq "0.0.0.0"}
```

If what you have is a private IP address

```
Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface | Where-Object {$_.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress -eq "0.0.0.0"}
```

If you have classic deployment, these two should help you:

```
Get-AzureVM | Where-Object{$_.IpAddress -eq "0.0.0.0"}
Get-AzureVM | Where-Object{$_.PublicIPAddress -eq "0.0.0.0"}
```

If what you have is something classic deployment but not a VM. This is the closest solution I can come up so far. It finds you the rogue cloud service **BUT** also returns an error for each cloud service don't have a matching IP and takes about 20s to scan each cloud service.

```
Get-AzureService | ForEach-Object {Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $_.ServiceName | Where-Object {$_.VirtualIPs.Address -like "0.0.0.0"}}
```